# App release wont work correctly, but debug apk works

Tags: flutter, dart

When I compile the app one screen does not work like it should be, it works when testing it using run in my android studio I don't know where i got wrong though. This screen include image_picker and firebase and firestorage hope any can help me

I expect the screens both work in testing and compiled apk

Comment: please share more information like, screenshots, code etc. refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you added `INTERNET` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file before releasing?

Comment: I add those permission but still doesnt work maybe ill just use the debug apk version thanks.

Comment: I see what the problem was i added internet permission but still the apk doesnt know that there is internet permission already thats why it cant connect

Comment: you need to give internet permission at app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml for release mode.

Comment: Yes i already included but the problem is its still not giving internet im just confuse it should work right, the screens with problems is those with NetworkImage Widget only connecting to firebase can get access

Comment: can you please share the method how you are creating apk?

Comment: flutter build apk
thats the code i just dont know how to provide image
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
that line already included i dont know why it doesnt work on networkimage widget
maybe some http issues but im just using firebase storage for images